# Securing Service Bus

Tags: azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

We are planning to use Service Bus option for our project. 
It is going to be a Client-Server project and following is the architecture of the project :-

Server :- A WCF Self hosted Server interacting with Service Bus and exposing various methods. We are going to host Server on MS Network.

Client :- A net application, interacting with the Server through Service Bus. Client will be distributed to various end user.

Technology :- Client and Server both are .Net applications. Client is developed in WPF and Server is a self-hosted console application.

Binding :- NetTcpRelayBinding is being used.

**Queries**

1. Do we require to open firewall port on client-side for communication with Service Bus?
2. Options available for securing the application and how to make it more secure?
3. When Service Bus is being used, do we need to apply WCF security options. I feel we should not but need to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers:

1. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706729.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee732535.aspx
2. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd582773.aspx
3. Yes. The Service Bus security model adds an additional layer to protect the endpoint. It does not replace end-to-end security.

Comment: links all just go to ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/   https://web.archive.org/web/20120320084751/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706729.aspx  http://web.archive.org/web/20120128214624/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee732535.aspx   http://web.archive.org/web/20130523125840/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd582773.aspx  at least show you the old content